# CakePHP: multi-deep model queries

Tags: cakephp

I have the following models:

Book -> hasOne(Subcategory) -> belongsTo(Category)

I have to make the following query:

```
select c.ds_category,count(*) from categories c,subcategories sc,books b
where b.id_subcategory=sc.id_subcategory and sc.id_category=c.id_category
group by c.ds_category
```

In the Book model I've defined

```
var $hasOne="Subcategory";
```

In the subcategories model I've defined

```
var $belongsTo="Category";
```

The problem is that when I call

`return $this->find("all");`

I cannot get categories table so cannot make group by.
Ive tried to define `$recursive=2` but I did not run.
Can anyone help me in finding a way to get also Categories items?

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't Book belongsTo Subcategory? And you should use Containable to have a more control over find.